# What does Rails ActiveRecord find return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using the find method as follows:

```
@records = Effort.find( :all,
                        :select => 'full_name, taskType, sum(hours)',
                        :group => 'full_name, taskType',
                        ...
@records.each do |record|
```

The query works fine.  What I am confused about is how to access the sum(hours) value.  I've tried the following:

```
record.sum(hours) # undefined local variable hours
record.sum_hours  # sum_hours undefined
record[2]         # Gives empty string
record[3]         # Same, just double checking where the index might start...
```

I'm a bit stuck how to access the value!  If I add `<%= debug @records %>` to my view, I see debugging output such as this:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Effort
  attributes:
    full_name: admin
    taskType: Pre-Sales
    sum(hours): '16'
```

Comment: Can you try with sum_hours_? I have the idea that AR replaces all symbols with underscores.

Comment: Unfortunately not - undefined method sum_hours_

Comment: Have you tried to use an alias for that? eg. `:select => 'full_name, taskType, sum(hours) AS total_hours'` and then you could access it calling for `record.total_hours`. I'm not sure about this anyway.

Comment: +1 Yep just tried that and it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve with this query?  Are you trying to get the sum of all `Effort`'s hours or group them by some other means?

The query below

```
@records = Effort.find( :all,
                        :select => 'full_name, taskType, sum(hours)',
                        ...
```

Will only ever return 1 value, because you're selecting a `sum(hours)` in there, which results in SQL aggregating the results into the first row. This means you'll always get your first `Effort` row, with a `sum(hours)` field set to the total amount of hours spent on all efforts.

If you just want the sum of all `Effort` hours, you can do this:

`Effort.sum(:hours)`

If you're looking to sum hours based on some other criteria, please update your question.

**EDIT**

In this case you could do something like this,

`@records = Effort.group(:full_name, :taskType).sum(:hours)`

You'll end up with a hash that looks like this:

`[full_name, taskType] => count`

i.e.

```
['baking cookies', 'baking'] => 12
['baking cakes', 'baking'] => 2
...
```

You could iterate over it like:

```
@records.each do | (full_name, task_type), hours |
  puts 'Full Name: #{full_name}, Task Type: #{task_type}, Total Hours: #{hours}'
end
```

Comment: exactly. you must use an aggregate function like group() if you want multiple rows, as i already stated in another of your questions. for such complex calculations, see [calculate](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Yes I am using a group by on the other two fields of the select clause - I was trying to minimise my question to the relevant parts

Comment: Thanks, that is a much cleaner solution than what I was doing!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it works, but you might want to try this :

```
@sums = Effort.sum(:hours, 
                   :group => [:project_task_id, :user_id],
                   :joins => [:project_task, :user])
```

it should give you an array of records. You should then normally be able to collect these:

```
@array = @sums.collect do |aggregate|
           [aggregate.project_task.name, aggregate.user.name, aggregate.hours]
         end
```

Answer (score 0):

While looking back at my post and the debug output, it suddenly occurred to me it is right there on the page:

```
record.attributes[ 'sum(hours)' ]
```

I suppose that stuff like `record.full_name` is really a convenience method for accessing the attributes array?

Comment: Yes, it will look at your attribute and grab the appropriate key from your attributes hash.  If you have it working go ahead, I'd recommend just taking a quick look at my updated solution to see if that can clean up your code a bit.